# ¿Es lo mismo "platicar" que "conversar" o "hablar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, méxico

Estaba viendo ayer un vídeo de un programa de televisión de México y me fijé que usaban con frecuencia "platicar" para refererise a "hablar" o "conversar".

Consulté el DRAE y vi la siguiente definición:

> **[platicar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=platicar&o=h)**
>
> De practicar.
>
> 1. intr. conversar (‖ hablar). U. t. c. tr.

Me surgió entonces la duda: ¿son palabras completamente equivalentes, la una propia del dialecto mexicano y la otra genérica, o existe algún matiz entre ellas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los verbos platicar, conversar, hablar, (a veces hasta charlar), suelen ser utilizados de manera indistinta.

Sin embargo en su forma sustantiva solo suele usarse, plática, conversación, charla.

```
Ellos tuvieron una plática.
Ellos tuvieron una conversación.
Ellos tuvieron una charla.
```

En México, charla suele usarse en un sentido más formal.

Comment: Pues nunca he usado ni he visto que utilicen charlar más que jugando. Es una palabra que oímos en los doblajes y en programas de otros países, es muy posible que por eso suene más elegante y formal, pero no tiene uso real.

Comment: ¿Entonces no hay contextos específicos en los que se dice "platicar" en lugar de "conversar"?

Comment: No, al menos en México no se usan en contexto específicos.

Comment: Al igual que "charlar" no tiene un uso real en México, así mismo "conversar" es raro de escuchar de manera cotidiana. Por lo regular se utiliza "platicar" para todos los casos e incluso es más común "hablar" antes que conversar o charlar.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que "platicar" es un verbo más común en México. Mi padastro mexicano lo usa todo el tiempo, pero no me recuerdo haberlo escuchado cuando hablaba con hablantes nativos de Sudamérica o España.

Answer (score 3):

Es lo mismo pero solo en México y de hecho es la forma que más usan.

En el resto de los países de habla hispana no usamos la palabra `platicar` y son más frecuentes `conversar` y `hablar`.

Si usas `platicar` fuera de México seguro también te van a entender porque vemos mucha televisión con doblaje mexicano.

Answer (score 1):

En España no se usa "platicar", sino "hablar", "charlar" o "conversar". De mejor a peor opción:

- "Charlar" es la versión informal de "platicar": una conversación informal, ligera, como las que se tienen en el ascensor, con la familia o con los amigos. Aunque no tiene por qué ser así, casi siempre implica que el tema tratado no es demasiado serio, o al menos que no se trata con demasiada gravedad. También suele implicar una conversación entre dos personas, o al menos entre poca gente.
- "Conversar" suena un poco forzado en España, aunque a lo mejor no tanto en otros países. Se entiende perfectamente, pero no es la mejor opción. Se suele usar más en el lenguaje escrito que en el hablado.
- "Hablar" es la opción más neutral, y sirve para cualquier tipo de conversación. Por ejemplo, serviría tanto para hablar de negocios con tu jefe como para explicarle algo a un amigo. Aparte, puede usarse tanto en conversaciones uno a uno como para dirigirse a un grupo de personas.

Ante la duda, "hablar" es la opción más segura. Pero conviene atreverse a usar las más coloquiales de vez en cuando, porque son las que denotan mejor conocimiento del idioma. Y si te equivocas, serán las que más diviertan a los nativos ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Es exactamente lo mismo, solo que en algunos países requieren a una de las formas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tenemos distintas voces consideradas en general como  sinónimos e intercambiables, esto suele ser cierto *grosso modo* ya que  normalmente existe una buena razón para la existencia de tal variedad.

El castellano tiene un vocabulario particularmente rico en sinónimos, preciada propiedad para los autores, poetas, y músicos ya que ofrece con mucha frecuencia una amplia gama de alternativas para lograr las expresiones deseadas, que a la vez de cumplir con la misión primaria de comunicar una idea, permite hacerlo no solo en caprichosas y rebuscadas figuras, sino también creando sutiles *matices* de la idea general.

En este caso cada uno de estos sustantivos tiene una ***connotación*** que lo distingue de los demás y lo hace más idóneo en algunos casos cuando se desea transmitir alguna idea con algunas premisas implícitas y la connotación del sustantivo es el vehículo para ello.

Consideren las siguentes frases y sus premisas implícitas y la *connotación* de cada sustantivo será clara:

> El **hablar,** es *conditio sine qua non* para **platicar**
>   Sin embargo, el **platicar** sobre un tema suele ser algo informal. En contraste **charlar** requiere seriedad,

Es por ello que

> "Los estudiantes **platican** entre ellos, después de haber **charlado** seriamente con el director. Y ninguno de estos personajes ha dejado de **hablar** desde que este enunciado inició.