# How to talk about *codeswitching* in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, bilingüismo

I originally encountered the term "codeswitching" as a term to describe how a bilingual person might inadvertently, without noticing, switch from language A to B within a sentence or paragraph, and perhaps at some subsequent point switch back again.  The trigger might be a borrowed word or phrase from the other language, or a name from the other culture, such as *George Washington* or *Benito Juárez*.  Bilingual families and communities develop their own style of codeswitching.  For example, Tex Mex has fairly well established patterns of codewitching that give this hybrid dialect a distinctive sound, different from the Puerto Rican style of accommodating language fluidity.

There are specialists who study that.  I will leave the details of that study to those specialists.  Today, I just want to ask my colleagues here how to translate "codeswitching" to Spanish, in other words, how to speak in Spanish about the *phenomenon of codeswitching* without having to use a loan word from English.  And first I want to make sure everyone understands what the word means.  Let's take a conversation in Spanish.  Let's say Person A is fully bilingual.  We've all experienced this (although some individuals are more prone to codeswitching than others): Say I'm yakking with someone in Spanish.  I happen to mention an English word or name, and my train veers off the Spanish track over to the English track, where I stay until either:

- (a) I realize what happened, and awkwardly lift my train up off the English track and carry it back over to the Spanish track; or
- (b) I spend extensive time rolling along that English track with no embarrassment or regret until experiencing another sudden !!Codeswitch!! and I'm back on the Spanish track, where I might or might not realize I've switched trains again....

Nowadays, the term goes beyond languages and now extends to dialects, cultural attitudes and beliefs, body language, and political attitudes, beliefs and behaviors.

I'll be happy if you can help me find ways of talking about the simple version -- the linguistic type of codeswitching, in bilingualism.

**Edit to add**:

For the bilingual person, a codeswitch can be embarrassing, if the bilingual person is talking to a monolingual person.  Especially if the bilingual person was assuming the other person had a level of knowledge of the other language that he turns out not to have. (This is not to say that I personally think that anyone who experiences this *should* feel embarrassed or ashamed.  I'm just describing what I've experienced and observed.)

Comment: This is a very interesting question, as I've learnt the concept of codeswitching that I didn't know before, and some curious English verbs such as _to yak_: to talk persistently.

Comment: @Charlie - Well, it doesn't *have* to be persistently, and when I used it in this post, it wasn't.  I used it as an informal equivalent of "chatting" or "having an informal conversation."  I had some trouble finding an accurate (in my opinion) definition.  But http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yak looks pretty good.

Comment: I used the definition I found on Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @Charlie - It wasn't your fault.  I was surprised how many dictionaries I had to try before I found one that fit with the meaning of "yak" that I was using.  If I had come up completely empty I was going to post a question at ELU. Here, I can give you a nice example.  Say A and B are conversing and C comes over to ask A a question.  C begins with "Sorry to interrupt, I wanted to ask a little question about the meeting agenda." Then A might reassure C that it was perfectly fine, by saying "It's okay, we were just yakking about this weather.  I was just saying that if I don't see the sun soon...

Comment: ... I'm going to put my house on the market....  Let me just grab a copy of the agenda.  Okay.  What was your question?"  If this whole conversation were in Spanish, I would have written "Estábamos platicando acerce de bla bla."  But "platicar" is a Mexicanism, I think, so I don't know what it would be for your region.// In short, if I hear the word "yak," then I know it wasn't an uninterruptible, serious dialogue, but something more informal and interruptible.  Nevertheless, it needn't be persistent.  In my opinion.  (You're welcome to post on ELU.) // It's a word I like a lot.

Comment: That could be a nice question for this site, to find a word that conveys the meaning of "to talk, especially uninterruptedly and idly".

Comment: @Charlie - Following up on your idea I looked around to see what's been covered already and found https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15225/9385.  Apparently *charlar* is the equivalent of *platicar* when in Spain.  Also DGaleano said that because of dubbing of TV and movies, "platicar" will be widely understood.  (Do you think that's right, by the way?)

Comment: In Mexican usage both *charlar* and *platicar* are widely understood, the former term being associated with snobbish/hipster dialogue while more humble and down to earth dialogue would be referred to by the the latter. This would be very nuanced usage, however; with mostly everyone taking both terms as synonyms and valid alternatives for cacophony avoidance.

Comment: @hlecuanda - ¿Has ido a la página que encontré?  Quizás tienes algo que aportar ahí.

Comment: @Charlie - I just reread your comment again and realized that the definition I cited isn't very good either.  "To talk, especially uninterruptedly and idly" -- doesn't sound right to me.  I think I misread it and thought it said "to talk, especially interruptably and idly."  Sigh. // But maybe I like to yak and am defining the word differently than 99.9% of all other English speakers.

Answer (score 6):

**Alternancia de código** or **cambio de código** are the linguistic terms used in Spanish:

> Por alternancia de código o cambio de código entendemos el empleo alternativo de dos (o más) lenguas o dialectos en un discurso. Dicha alternancia es un fenómeno natural y común entre individuos bilingües, cuya competencia pragmática les permite escoger (incluso de un modo inconsciente) entre uno u otro código, según el interlocutor, la situación, el tema o el propósito de la interacción.
>
> - [*Centro Virtual Cervantes*, Diccionario de términos clave de ELE](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/diccio_ele/diccionario/alternanciacodigo.htm)

Comment: "Cambio de código" rolls off my tongue easier.  Will that one be understood as well by non-linguists as the other?

Comment: I doubt a layperson would be familiar with either term, so feel free to use whichever you prefer; they're both used in the literature, with *cambio* being used more frequently: Google Scholar - [*cambio*](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22cambio+de+código%22) (2,900 hits); [*alternancia*](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22alternancia+de+código%22) (1,010 hits)

Answer (score 3):

Esta respuesta dista de ser universal y tal vez sea solo válida en el contexto regional y cultural al que se refiere.

---

En el específico caso de las ciudades fronterizas de México con los E.E.U.U. así como al interior de comunidades de inmigrantes predominantemente hispanoparlantes de la Unión Americana, se da con frecuencia este tipo de "saltos" entre un idioma y otro.

La incidencia suele ser mayor en el caso de familias que han sufrido algún cisma cultural generacional, por ejemplo, la primera generación de inmigrantes hablan castellano como lengua nativa y sus hijos o segunda generación; han sido educados y han aprendido el inglés como lengua principal en su formación educativa escolar y ademas han aprendido  y usan el castellano como lengua adicional en el ámbito familiar o hacia adentro de sus comunidades que suelen ser relativamente compactas  y tienen el mismo legado cultural u origien nacional.

Es frecuente escuchar conversaciones completamente fluidas y perfectamente inteligibles en este ambiente al tenor de:

> The other day at school the teacher assigned us a science project, and I need to ask my *abuelo que si me ayuda para hacerlo, solo necesito que me preste* his tools for a few hours *y después se las llevo a su trabajo* I just need to borrow them *el no necesita hacer nada*

En mi experiencia, bsta con sostener conversaciones frecuentes con miembros de estas comunidades y si se es razonablemente bilingüe, después de cierto tiempo uno mismo hace estos cambios de lenguaje incluso de manera automática e inconsciente, es decir no te das cuenta hasta *after the fact* (*)

A esto le llaman coloquialmente (de manera *jocosamente recursiva*, además) ***switchear*** entre idiomas, Pronunciado a la manera inglesa *suich*

Recuerdo haber escuchado referencias a gerundios y participios siguiendo ambas ortografías, inglesa y **tambien** castellana: "Fulanito está *switcheando* mucho" así como "En ese grupo *hacen* mucho ***switching*** al ingles".

En general creo que es una construcción informal pero en cierta forma sobreenrendida ente los miembros de la comunidad, que conjugan y forman *al vuelo* diversas declinaciones en ambos idiomas, surgiendo una especie de *creole* o criollo similar al fenómeno ocurrido en las Antillas holandesas con el inglés, holandés y dialectos africanos entreverados, o en la Louisiana en EE. UU. Con el inglés, francés, y dialectos africanos también.

Hay que resaltar que el ***switcheo*** es un fenómeno distinto a la formación de sustantivos híbridos, cognatos y un vocabulario al que llamamos *spanglish* (analogo al *Portuñol* que se habla en las regiones fronterizas de Brasil y -supongo- Portugal y España ) y de uso frecuente en la frontera donde predominantemente se habla castellano.

Un ejemplo de esos sustantivos **spanglish** que se usan se manera espontánea en frases totalmente en castellano es el caso de **Parkear** (estacionar /aparcar /*park*) **Apuchar** (presionar/*push*), **Dómpe** (volqueta / camión de volteo / *dump truck* ), **Baika** (bicicleta / *bike*) **Bas** (autobus, transporte urbano / *Bus* ) incluso **Taxis**, ( sorprendentemente impuestos o *taxes*), **Brekas** (frenos /*Brakes*). Hay que subrayar que es rarísimo ver alguna de estas palabras escritas, siendo su uso principalmente verbal

---

Insisto, esta respuesta está basada exclusivamente en mi experiencia con comunidades de inmigrantes hispanoparlantes de origen principalmente Mexicano y centroamericano en el área de Los Ángeles, San Diego y Tijuana; y el término *Switcheo* se entiende de esta manera irrepectivamente del origen de la comunidad.

Estoy seguro que habrá algún término más apropiado y universal, pero creí conveniente hacer la *anotación regional* debido a las condiciones y prevalencia del fenómeno que he podido experimentar.

(*): Irresistible ocasión de aplicar el *switcheo*.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar material sobre estos aspectos (por mi curiosidad)? 1 - pronunciación (me imagino que los jóvenes dicen *swicheo* y los más grandes dicen *eswicheo*, donde la S se oye como la Z de inglés; ¿es así?); 2 - un ejemplo del switcheo por parte de la mamá, y del abuelo, en el escenario de *tools* que planteaste (si es que los adultos lo muestran también -- quizás no); 3 - qué proporción de la población tiene dificultad para *no* switchear en ciertos contextos, y si eso les coarta o limita o frustra en algo.  Perdón , parece que te estoy pidiendo un capítulo de libro. Pero...

Comment: ... es que tu respuesta fue demasiado fascinante.

Comment: @aparente001 agregué algunos detalles que solicitaste, tal vez valga la pena continuar en otra pregunta pues el tema da para mucho

Comment: Me encantan los ejemplos que pusiste, porque muestran lo rápida que se puede dar la evolución del idioma, y me da una mirada breve pero encantadora de la cultura que describes. // Me parece muy buena idea ir explorando todo esto con más preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: George López, a Mexican-American stand-up comedian uses code switching and immigrant idiosyncrasies to great success in his monologues, that are both hilarious and thought provoking: https://youtu.be/Z13CVD0idrM there are loads of examples in his monologues.

Answer (score 1):

I was dismayed to hear that [most people wouldn't understand it](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/how-to-talk-about-codeswitching-in-spanish?noredirect=1#comment42857_26029)("I doubt a layperson would be familiar with either term").  That used the be the case in English but it's coming into more general use now in English (e.g. podcast [Code Switch](https://www.npr.org/podcasts/510312/codeswitch)).

I'd like to propose some other ideas that hopefully give more of the feeling that comes with *codeswitch*:

**giro de lengua**

But maybe *viro* or *virage* would also be candidates.

and I'd like to invite other participants to brainstorm with me on this.

Comment: The problem with *giro de la lengua*  is that it already exists with another meaning. **[giro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JDUFomi|JDVj0a7):** 3. m. Tratándose del lenguaje o estilo, estructura especial de la frase, o manera de estar ordenadas las palabras para expresar un concepto.

Comment: @blonfu - Gracias.  Creo que entendería esto mejor con un ejemplo.  ¿Quieres plantear una pregunta, y luego autoresponder?